# как создать динамический многомерный ассоциативный массив?

Tags: php

Суть вопроса заключается в следующем - есть массивчик, полученный по средствам `explode`. В этом массиве может содержаться от 1 до 5 элементов. Всё летит с космоса, т.е. неизвестные значения. Необходимо сделать следующее - собрать многомерный ассоциативный массив на лету, например:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "Голова"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "Глаз"
}
```

Как получить:

```
array(1) {
  ["Голова"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Глаз"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Вероятнее всего, на следующей итерации цикла прилетит строка "Голова Ухо", в итоге должно получиться:

```
array(1) {
  ["Голова"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Глаз"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["Ухо"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Поделитесь советом или несложным кодом.

Comment: array_flip() вам в помощь

Comment: Эдуард, спасибо за совет, а поподробнее можно? эта функция меняет key и value местами, нет необходимости этого делать в моей задаче, или я чего-то не догоняю, сложность на данном этапе (для меня) заключается в том, чтоб создать массив в массиве ... в массиве ... в массиве при необходимости, из рандомного кол-ва элементов... и если начало - т.е. 1 элемент массива уже есть в массиве, то мы это учитываем и запихиваем следующий элемент дальше по глубине, глубина может достигать 5 ступеней, а может быть и 1! куда сувать ваш array_flip()? 0_o

Comment: я с первого прочтения не верно понял суть задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим на вход вы получаете набор строк с разделителями.

```
$input = [
    "голова",
    "голова/ухо",
    "голова/глаз/зрачок",
    "тело/нога",
    "тело/нога/колено",
];

$result = [];
```

Каждую строку вы пропускаете через `explode` и затем строите некоторое дерево частей тела :)

```
foreach($input as $str){
    $parts = explode("/", $str);

    $r = &$result;
    foreach($parts as $p){
        if(!array_key_exists($p, $r)){
            $r[$p] = [];
        }
        $r = &$r[$p];
    }
}
```

Заводите ссылочную переменную, изначально указывающую на сам массив. Далее берете первый фрагмент тела. Смотрите, есть ли такой ключ в массиве-ссылке или  нет. Если нет, то добавляете его. Заменяете ссылку уже на этот добавленный или существующий элемент.

```
Array (
    [голова] => Array (
        [ухо] => Array
            (
            )
        [глаз] => Array (
                [зрачок] => Array
                    (
                    )
            )
    )
    [тело] => Array (
        [нога] => Array (
                [колено] => Array
                    (
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

Comment: ДА! это именно то что надо, работа/задача выполнена на 100% Большое спасибо!