Рекурсивный перебор элементов массива с выводом в виде древа PHP
Доброго времени суток!
Есть массив:
$arr = [
    'index.php',
    'f.txt',
    'dir/f.txt',
    'dir/dir2/dir3/f2.md',
    'var/www/localhost/ghost.html',
]

Нужно перебрать его так, чтобы потом вывести как:
+ **dir**
    + **dir**
        + **dir2**
            + **dir3**
                + f2.md
    + f.txt
+ **var**
    + **www**
        + **localhost**
            + ghost.html
+ f.txt
+ index.php


Перебирайте. Выводите. А в чём заключается вопрос?

преобразовать в дерево как то так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/714363/223826

<?php
$arr = [
    'index.php',
    'f.txt',
    'dir/f.txt',
    'dir/dir2/dir3/f2.md',
    'var/www/localhost/ghost.html',
];

function output_tree_element_with_sublements( $element, $level = 0 ) {
    for( $i = 0; $i < $level * 4; $i++ ) { echo " "; }
    if ( preg_match('/\//', $element) ) {
        $element = explode('/', $element);
        echo "+ **".$element[0]."**\n";
        array_shift( $element );
        $element = implode('/',  $element );
        $level++;
        output_tree_element_with_sublements( $element, $level );
    } else { echo "+ ".$element."\n"; }
}

foreach( $arr as $element ) {
    if ( preg_match('/\//', $element) ) {.
        //$level = 0;
        output_tree_element_with_sublements( $element );
    }
}
foreach( $arr as $element ) {
    if ( !preg_match('/\//', $element) ) { echo "+ ".$element."\n"; }
}


+ **dir**
    + f.txt
+ **dir**
    + **dir2**
        + **dir3**
            + f2.md
+ **var**
    + **www**
        + **localhost**
            + ghost.html
+ index.php
+ f.txt


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
